# How to get the exact ubuntu kernel source files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I got a binary kernel module provided by 3rd party, which expects version magic `5.4.0-81-generic SMP mod_unload modversions aarch64` of the kernel. It means that I need to grab the exact source tree to build the kernel for using the `.ko`, on my own customized SoC platform.

Now I have serveral questions for this task:

- `5.4.0-81-generic`: `5.4.0` seems refer to the official kernel version `5.4`; what is `81`? Is this a patch level (or abi number)?
- Can I obtain the exact source tree by patching the official kernel version `5.4`? If so, where can I find the corresponding patch file for patch level `81`?
- I can do `apt install linux-source-5.4.0`, but there is no patch level on the linux-source pkg name. However, to install the headers, there are patch level on the pkg name, e.g. `apt install linux-header-5.4.0-81`? Why the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu collects its own patched sources into a source package which you can download.

The version number includes a build version; the upstream sources (the Linux kernel) does not have an Ubuntu build, but each released build has a specific version with a number after the dash and you want exactly the right one.

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

If you want the full sources,

```
apt source linux-generic
```

though in practice you want to read the instruction it prints and download the sources from Github.

Perhaps see also https://ubuntu.com/kernel and https://linuxhint.com/install-linux-kernel-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you. Following the 1st link you provided, I reached the following page with detailed instruction on how to download full kernel source repository for 20.04 (`focal`): `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide`.